# tableview addsubview to custom cell

Tags: uitableview, swift

How to add a `UISwitch` using `addsubview` to a specific section and row of tablview?

For example:

```
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 12
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as cell_TableViewCell

        var oneObject = UISwitch(frame: CGRect(x: 260, y: 5, width: 50, height: 30)) as UISwitch

        if indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 0
        {
            oneObject.tag = 8
            cell.contentView.addSubview(oneObject)
        }

        return cell
    }
```

This tableview will keep adding to a random cell when scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` should be used only to set properties of a cell, not add or remove subviews. Since the cell gets reused for every table row (in your example, anyway), adding the switch in one call winds up affecting all rows, even at random-seeming times. A better approach is to add the `UISwitch` to the prototype cell, and then hide or show it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Try to add UISwitch manually in customCell class and self.addsubview(UISwitch()).and create function to trigger hide/show uiswitch.BUT It still not working / same result

Comment: Where are you calling the addSubview:? In the custom cell's constructor?

Comment: i tried in constructor or function . none of them is working.

Comment: its works. just have to set others cells too. thanks!